# Pls answer. My code is not working. The cout is not working

Tags: c++, integer, cin, cout, temperature

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int C; //let C be Celsius
    int F; //let F be Fahrenheit
    
    cout << "Enter the temperature in Celsius: ";
    cin >> C;
    
    cout << "Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: ";
    cin >> F;
    
    fahrenheit = (C * 9 / 5) + 32
    celsius = (F - 32) * 5 / 9
    
    cout << "The computed Fahrenheit value from temperature in Celsius: " << fahrenheit << endl;
    cout << "The computed Celsius value from temperature in Fahrenheit: " << celcius << endl;
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) then the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...) Notice that `#include <conio.h>` is non-standard. See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Enable all warnings and debug info (e.g. with GCC compiler using `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Comment: It's clear that there are gaps in what you were taught by your instructors. This is not your fault. It is also clear that this is homework. SO is not a place to get your homework done for you. "My code doesn't work" and posting just the code is not an appropriate question. Neither is one that can be fixed by simply looking up proper examples of code.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to say what 'not working' means. There are many problems with this code.

But looking at the code the main problem seems to be that you are using *integer division*.

The value of `9/5` is `1`, not `1.8`. In C++ when you divide one integer by another the result is **always** another integer. Instead if you want a fraction you should use `9.0/5.0`.

In C++ is always important that you pick the correct *types* for your variables. Temperature is a quantity that *varies continuously*, so using integers for temperatures is wrong. Use `float` or `double` instead.

You've failed to declare two of your variables `celcius` and `fahrenheit`.

You are also missing semi colons at the end of some of your statements.

Standard library objects such as `cin`, `cout` etc. exist in the `std` namespace should be referenced with *qualified names*, `std::cin` etc.

Finally if you are going to use `getch` to pause your program, it must be **before** your `return` not afterwards.

Here's your program with these corrections.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    double C; //let C be Celsius
    double F; //let F be Fahrenheit
    
    std::cout << "Enter the temperature in Celsius: ";
    std::cin >> C;
    
    std::cout << "Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: ";
    std::cin >> F;
    
    double fahrenheit = (C * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0;
    double celsius = (F - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
    
    std::cout << "The computed Fahrenheit value from temperature in Celsius: " << fahrenheit << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The computed Celsius value from temperature in Fahrenheit: " << celcius << std::endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see there are many problems with your code. You can't program by getting things roughly correct. It has to be exactly correct or it will not work.

Comment: Your "fix" still has the underlying problem. `cout`, `cin`, and `endl` don't exist. You need to prepend them with the proper scope.

Comment: @Casey Good point, I'll sort it out.